# How to do static global lighting in OpenGL without using gluLookAt?

Tags: opengl

I'm currently trying to figure out how to create a static light without using gluLookAt. This means gluLookAt stays at its default settings.

I am using gluPerspective.

I use glRotate and glTranslate to move everything based on the angle that I'm looking and on the x,y,z position of where I am.

```
glRotatef(currentState.rot[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);        // Rotate the camera on the x-axis (looking up and down)
glRotatef(currentState.rot[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);        // Rotate the camera on the  y-axis (looking left and right)
glTranslatef(-currentState.pos[0], -currentState.pos[1], -currentState.pos[2]);    // Translate the modelview matrix to the position of the camera
```

I don't know how to approach this issue. If someone could give me a direction of where to go, I would appreciate it.

Comment: All functions beginning with `glu` are completely superfluous, and can be replaced with a combination of regular `gl` functions.  For example, `gluPerspective()` is nothing more than a wrapper around `glFrustum()`, and if you look at the manual pages or the source code, you can see exactly how `gluLookAt()` is implemented.

Comment: Alright, i'll look into gluLookAt and see how that works.
But for some reason, whenever I do lighting, it always ends up strange.